# layout inflator problem

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

in my application i want to show transparent panel on click of alert dialog ok button.alert dialog is displayes in ontap method of mapview.i have created seperate class for transperant panel and now inflating that class on Ok button click.

while inflating i'm getting exception layout inflator exception caused by class not found exception.

here is my code for that

```
@Override
    protected boolean onTap(int i) {
        final Animation animShow;
        final Animation animHide;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = null;

        OverlayItem item=getItem(i);
        builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
        builder.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        animShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(FindFishActivity.this, R.anim.popup_show);
        animHide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( FindFishActivity.this, R.anim.popup_hide);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Show Info",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                onShowInfo();

            }

            public void onShowInfo() {
                LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(FindFishActivity.this);
                View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial5,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutID));
                transparentPanel=(TransparentPanel)view.findViewById(R.id.popup_window);
                transparentPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                transparentPanel.startAnimation(animShow);

            }
        });
        builder.show();


        return true;
    }
```

my transperantpanel class which is extended from linear layout

public  class TransparentPanel extends LinearLayout 
{ 
    private Paint   innerPaint, borderPaint ;

```
public TransparentPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public TransparentPanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    innerPaint = new Paint();
    innerPaint.setARGB(225, 75, 75, 75); //gray
    innerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    borderPaint = new Paint();
    borderPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
    borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    borderPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
}

public void setInnerPaint(Paint innerPaint) {
    this.innerPaint = innerPaint;
}

public void setBorderPaint(Paint borderPaint) {
    this.borderPaint = borderPaint;
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    RectF drawRect = new RectF();
    drawRect.set(0,0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

    canvas.drawRoundRect(drawRect, 5, 5, innerPaint);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(drawRect, 5, 5, borderPaint);

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

and my xml file

```
<view class="com.android.fishdemo.FindFishActivity.MyOverlays$TransparentPanel"
        android:id="@+id/popup_window" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="1px"
        android:background="@drawable/white">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_bar_gradient">

        <Button android:id="@+id/hide_popup_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:layout_marginRight="10px"
                android:paddingLeft="5px"
                android:paddingRight="5px"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                android:textSize="12px"
                android:text="Close"
                android:background="@drawable/button_black_rounded_out"/>

        <LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1px"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/hide_popup_button"
                        android:background="@drawable/white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView   android:id="@+id/location_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16px"
                android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5px"/>

    <TextView   android:id="@+id/location_description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@drawable/white"
                android:layout_margin="5px"/>

</view>
```

please help me...
thanks

Comment: I'm not going to help you for two reasons: 1) you have simply thrown a bunch of code at us and basically asked us to do all the work for you, and 2) you haven't accepted a single answer to your previous questions, thereby showing little to no gratitude for the help you've received in the past.

Comment: try putting the onShowInfo() method outside the scope of Alert Dialog as a class method and then use Layout Inflator.... in that method..